# Get the item that maximizes a function together with the maximized value from a python list

Tags: python, list, lambda, key, max

As the code below, I know how to get the item that maximize a function from a list, but I also want to get the maximized value together with the item. In reality I have a very computationally expensive function so I don't want to run the function again. Here I just use a sigmoid function as an example.

```
import math

lst = list(range(100))
maxnum = max(lst, key=lambda x: 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x)))
maxval = 1 / (1 + math.exp(-maxnum))
print(maxnum, maxval)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tuple to store both `maxnum` and `maxval`, as follows, then pass as key the value in the second position (using [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) in the code below):

```
import math
from operator import itemgetter

lst = list(range(100))


def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

result = max((e, sigmoid(e))  for e in lst, key=itemgetter(1))


print(result)
```

**Output**

```
(37, 1.0)
```

Comment: This is great answer. Just curious, is it possible to still use a lambda expression?

Comment: Where do you want to use the lambda expression? You can change itemgetter by a lambda expression, but not sure what you mean

Comment: I get the error "Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument".

Comment: ```result = max(((e, sigmoid(e))  for e in lst), key=itemgetter(1))``` works for me